# ListView update/edit/delete command error

Tags: sql, listview, sql-update, edit

Working on a page that will display the results of an SQL query in a ListView. I have set up the data connection and set it to automatically create the Update, Delete and Add function to the DB.

I have got the ListView to populate correctly and I am able to Add fields to the database (so basically the Update and Select query is working).

Here is the SQL statement for the connection.... Seems too complicated for what I need it to do.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ListString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [pizzas] WHERE (([Id] = ?) OR ([Id] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [pizzas] ([Id], [type], [description], [inch9price], [inch11price], [inch13price]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ListString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [type], [description], [inch9price], [inch11price], [inch13price] FROM [pizzas]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [pizzas] SET [type] = ?, [description] = ?, [inch9price] = ?, [inch11price] = ?, [inch13price] = ? WHERE (([Id] = ?) OR ([Id] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="inch9price" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="inch11price" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="inch13price" Type="Decimal" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="inch9price" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="inch11price" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="inch13price" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Can you see anything wrong here?

When I try and delete or update the listview items I get this error...

> No value given for one or more required parameters.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wooooow.... I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question. For future reference, you need to replace the "?" fields in the SQL statement with the corresponding parameter. Man that was stupid of me...